# MVC 4 Input Submit Button not firing Action

Tags: forms, asp.net-mvc-4

I cannot get the my HttpPost action to fire.

In HomeController.cs I have the following:

```
public ActionResult TestForm() 
    {
        return View();
    }

[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult TestForm(TestForm testForm)
    {
        int x = 1;
        return View();
    }
```

In my View code I build my form with

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
```

{
....
}

The rendered HTML is

```
<form action="/Home/TestForm" method="post">    <div style="display: table">

    <div style="display: table-row">
        <div style="display: table-cell"><label for="Cmd">CMD String</label></div>
        <div style="display: table-cell">
            <input class="CmdForm" id="Cmd" name="Cmd" type="text" value="" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="display: table-row">
        <div style="display: table-cell"><label class="MacAddress" for="MacAddress">MAC Address</label></div>
        <div style="display: table-cell">
            <input id="MacAddress" name="MacAddress" type="text" value="" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="display: table-row">
        <div style="display: table-cell"></div>
        <div style="display: table-cell">
            <input type="button" value="Submit"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've put a break point at int x=1; just to see if it's hitting the function on button click but it does not hit it. Can someone give me some tips on what I might be missing?

Comment: 1) Use the more explicit `@using(Html.BeginForm("TestForm", "Home", FormMethod.Post))`. 2) Make sure you have a submit button `<button type="submit">Submit</button>`. 3) Then double check the rendered HTML to see if your form is properly written. 4) Watch the browser's network monitor (usually F12) to see if the request is actually made.

Comment: @Jasen 
thanks for the quick response. the generated html is 
<form action="/Home/TestForm" method="post">  and
....
 <input type="button" value="Submit"/> 
so that seems correct.

Comment: You should add the rendered form html as an edit to your question. But anyway, check that the browser really is making a request.

Comment: <input type="button" value="Submit"/> should be  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

Comment: You don't have a submit button so the form will never be submitted.

Answer (score 0):

You put a button for submission which is not of the right type. You should use `submit` as a type, not `button`.

Change the following code from

```
<div style="display: table-cell">
    <input type="button" value="Submit"/>
</div>
```

to

```
<div style="display: table-cell">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</div>
```